How can i create .env file in codemagic Flutter project
I use codemagic to deploy my flutter app, and I have a local .env file that is ignored by .gignore I don't know how I can create it on codemagic while keeping it ignored. ps: I only have the free version of codemagic
I have already tried to run some scripts before deployment but it does not work

usually you add environment variables in Codemagic UI and in your script you should have something like this
echo "MY_SECRET_1=$MY_SECRET_1" >> .env
echo "MY_SECRET_2=$MY_SECRET_2" >> .env

so this will create .env file with all required values
